# XMega bootloader - How to make use of the functions in assembly source file

Tags: avr, assembly, bootloader, atmel-studio, atxmega

Its been two days I'm trying to write a Bootloader for ATXMega32E5. The Atmel studio doesn't have `boot.h` header file supporting XMega.

As a result of searching and googling, I found two ASM header [sp_driver.S](https://github.com/bandtank/Xmega_Bootloader/blob/master/sp_driver.s) and [sp_driver.h](https://github.com/bandtank/Xmega_Bootloader/blob/master/sp_driver.h). Even after the two readings and trial, I couldn't find how to use that asm functions in the embedded C code.

If someone came across this way, do help me in creating a bootloader. Or to create a makefile linking the source and header with the C file. That way I can call the functions and I will make my own bootloader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions in the assembly file are just like any C functions that get linked by AVR-GCC when you include the sp_driver.S and sp_driver.h files and call those functions from your bootloader code. For instance, put this in your main code's header file:

`#include "sp_driver.h"`

and then call any of the functions from sp_driver, e.g.

`SP_EraseApplicationPage(Address);
 SP_WaitForSPM();`

Make sure the sp_driver.S is included in the compile list so the compiler and linker can find it.

Comment: How can i add it in the compiler list? I am using atmel studio. Thats what i am searching.. Couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: First, make sure you have sp_driver.h and sp_driver.S somewhere in your project folder or some subfolder. Then make sure the Solution Explorer is visible (View->Solution Explorer). Click on the button 'View all files' at the top of the solution explorer window. You should now be able to navigate to the sp_driver files. Right click and select 'Include in project'. That's it.